# Linux dosen't boot on cubietruck

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

After a kernel update on my CubieTruck running Ubuntu 16.04 my system dosen't boot anymore. I'm very beginner on Linux so I'm uploaded a photo of my screen during the booting process.

[image]

Comment: are you booting off an sd card or EMMC? It might be dead

Comment: I've installed my Linux on a SD Card. So I think it tries to reboot from SD Card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ![Screenshot of command line.]

Is the bit you need to be looking at.

Now an emmc and SD look about the same in linux (so chances are its the same) , but there's a few key things here.

*initially* the mmc is read and the boot file is read off that - the parts I've labelled 1,2 and 3 are ok 4-9 failed, which could indicate file system corruption. Interestingly, they're on the same partition, so it could be a bad update. If you have any important files, it might be worth loading the SD card into another system (or imaging the whole thing) for recovery. Considering that boot files are missing, you're not that experienced (chrooting for recovery is loads of fun on x86. Less so on an embedded system) - but the fs seems otherwise ok, a fresh install is your best and easiest bet.  If this happens after a fresh install, you may need to consider replacing the SD card as well

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. I've saved all my important files on SATA that I'm mounted into the system earlier. So I will try a new fresh installation of linux on the sd card